# Filtrar registros de uma tabela através de qualquer campo de inserção de dados

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-eventos, jquery-validate

Bom dia, o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte, tenho dois campos com inputs, 1 para Vendedor e outro para Cliente.

Abaixo destes campos tenho minha tabela que carrega os dados que vem do banco com todos os dados do objeto, com nome,data,tipo e valor, e se está revisado ou não.

O que estou tentando fazer é filtrar os dados que vem da tabela, se eu digitar no input text de Vendedor ou digitar no input text de Cliente, e clicar no botão Enter do teclado, vir os dados do banco através do nome do Cliente ou do nome do Vendedor que digitei em qualquer um dos inputs.

Estou iniciando com JQuery, e tentei fazer dessa maneira, vou deixar o trecho do código para alguma eventual ajuda.

Desde já, agradeço!

Meu form:

```
 <div id="Filtros" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            <div class="well">
                <form action="@Url.Action("Filtros")" method="POST" id="formFiltros">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="control-group">
                             <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdFornecedor, "Vendedor")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("FornecedorAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um vendedor..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdFornecedor)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa, "Adquirente")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um adquirente(nome ou cnpj)..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <button id="btnFiltro" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitFormFiltro();">
                            <i class="icon-filter icon-white"></i>Filtrar
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="limparFiltro();">
                            Limpar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

E o trecho de código que estou tentando pelo meu arquivo JavaScript:

```
    $("#formFiltros").on("kepress", function (e) {
        var k = event.keyCode || e.which;
        if (k == 13) {
            // filter and show result
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1)
            $("#formFiltros").submit()
        }
    });
```

Eu já tentei dessa maneira, fez o filtro, mas quando clicava no botão Enter, não me deu o resultado esperado, vou deixar o trecho de código que eu fiz e filtrou, mas não funcionou com o evento de click no Enter do teclado.

```
$("#GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete").on("keyup", function () {
        searchText = $(this).val();
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        searchText = searchText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $('.CelebreTableRow > td').each(function () {
             var currentTdText = $(this).text(),
                showcurrentTd = ((currentTdText.toLowerCase()).replace(/\s+/g, '')).indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
            $(this).toggle(showcurrentTd);
        });
    });
```

Obrigado pela atenção, espero ter deixado claro ou pelo menos ter explicado o problema que estou tentando resolver!

Comment: Opa, você disse que não teve o resultado esperado, qual o resultado que deu? Outra dúvida na sua pergunta é se você quer chamar o action do form ou só fazer um filtro local.

Comment: O filtro é executado somente para o nome e quando aperto a tecla Enter não aparece os dados do cliente que foi digitado no input. Quero filtrar local, como se fosse um submit com a tecla Enter, digitei o nome no input de nome, clico no Enter do teclado e ele me retorna os dados a partir do nome digitado no input.